# Why can't I sign on to Ebay or Craigslist?

Tags: blocked-services, blocked

If I'm being blocked from these sites, can I unblock?
Thanks.

Comment: To confirm, are you using Tor? (If not, then you're in the wrong place.) If you are, and those sites are blocking Tor users, then you'd need to look at using a bridge. Have a look at this thread: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/how-can-i-determine-if-tor-is-being-blocked?rq=1

Comment: Yes, using Tor.  Ok, will look.  And I know nothing about bridges.  Thx.

Comment: Looked up bridges.  Seems very complex.  Oi.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks - Bridges are for entering the Tor network. Not exiting. Using a bridge can help if your ISP blocks Tor. Not when the site you want to visit blocks Tor.

Comment: Ugh. Yes, @Jobiwan is right - ignore me. Apologies for the misleading suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If the website endpoint blocks Tor users, it seems to be almost impossible, but there's an option : take a look at SSH tunneling and take a VPS for such purposes. But if they've implanted a persistent cookie(like Evercookie) to your system, then it will not help you either. And there's an optional check : if the website side is not parsing Tor public lists of outpoints - it can be possible to obtain an exit node that is not publishing a standart "I'm an exit node" page